# Was “thee” ever used as a nominative?

Tags: archaicisms, thou-thee-thy

In *The Witch of Blackbird Pond*, a youth novel written in the 1950s and set in late-17th century Connecticut, the title character uses *thee* as a nominative throughout, moreover with third-person singular verb conjugations. (“Has thee looked for an answer?” rather than the correct “hast thou,” for example.)

It seems strange that a 1950s editor would have missed such mistakes in a Newberry award book. Is there any linguistic tradition of this usage at that time? The character is a Quaker, if that’s relevant.

Comment: Thou shalt see mistakes often in [Wardour Street English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wardour_Street_English).

Comment: @Robusto Noooo, it's _**Thee** shall see_!

Comment: I don't think this is an example of Wardour, actually. The author was a meticulous researcher.

Comment: Doesn't some some English dialect speech (e.g. Yorkshire) still have something similar?

Comment: @gidds Yeah, various Northern English dialects retain “thee” and “thou” (often “tha” in dialect spelling). There are several regional variations when it comes to possessives and conjugations and suchlike, but I haven't heard of any of them using “thee” in the nominative.

Comment: mudri & @gidds - most of the South Yorkshire variants I've ever heard barely differentiate at all, using 'tha' or 'thi' depending more on the initial sound of the word that follows than any strictly grammatical adherence. [I'm West Yorkshire, where it's not used at all, but worked many years just south of the 'dialect border', Castleford/Pontefract, where the usage starts.] e.g "Tha'll ave to behave thi'sen." [You'll have to behave yourself.]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The fact that the character is a Quaker is very relevant. Quakers used *thee* for both the nominative and objective cases long after most other English speakers had stopped using *thee* and *thou* and started using *you*. [See this blog entry](https://quakerlexicon.wordpress.com/2010/02/04/nominative-thee/),

So using the archaic 2nd-person pronouns was not a mistake. What may be a mistake is the use of *thee* instead of *thou* for the nominative — this shift of Quakers to using *thee* rather than *thou* took place approximately one hundred years after the novel was set, in the late eighteenth century.

On the other hand, the author may have deliberately decided to use this anachronistic language for artistic reasons. Quaker speech would definitely have stood out at the time, because Quakers used *thou* and *thee* for everybody, even on formal occasions. However, if the author had used this more authentic mode of Quaker speech, modern readers might not have realized that the Quaker characters were speaking any differently from the other characters, who would have used both *you* and *thou*, depending on the occasion and how well they knew the person they were taking to.

From the blog:

> Probably no word is more closely associated with Quakers in the popular imagination than *thee,* although very few Quakers actually still use it. The fact that Quakers continued to use *thee* long after most of the rest of the English-speaking world abandoned it is somewhat remarkable, but what I want to focus on more particularly here is the fact that even though Quakers retained *thee,* they eventually dropped *thou* (at least in colloquial style), using *thee* in its place.  A related change is the loss of the traditional *-est* second person singular verb ending, and its replacement with what looks like the third person singular form.  The result is that in Quaker speech, one says *Thee goes to meeting* instead of *Thou goest to meeting.*

The blog goes on to say:

> It should be recognized that nominative *thee* is not exclusive to Quakers, but is used in a number of regional English dialects, especially in western England.

and

> the use of nominative *thee* became popular among Quakers in the late 18th and early 19th centuries.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the author wrote the novel in his own 1950s Quaker dialect? If not, then how can it be consistent with the 17th century and not a mistake?

Comment: @Cerberus that seems to be what Peter's third paragraph suggests – artistic licence.

Comment: @WeatherVane: That paragraph wasn't there when Cerberus made the comment. (And I don't know whether it was a mistake or artistic license, but I'd give the author the benefit of doubt.)

Comment: @WeatherVane: OK now this answer is perfect.

Comment: By all accounts, Elizabeth George Spears was a thorough researcher, so I, too, tend to the idea that the author chose the anachronistic 18th century Quakerisms intentionally.

Comment: Here's some more on **thee** and **thou**.  'But Tibbals 1926 writes that "with all but a diminishing few, *thou* has quite dropt away". And Maxfield 1926 writes that  "*thou* is as much an archaism among Friends as it is with the rest of the English-speaking world, and has been so for some generations".'
 https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2732